# Post function not functioning as expected with database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am having some problems with this code. I am connecting to an SQL Database and it connects, but the post function doesn't appear to be working. When I inspect element and look at the network connections, it posts one thing, but not the other two things. If someone could help me out, that would be great.

Thanks,

Ben

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die("There is no connection to the server");
mysql_select_db("tutorial", $connection) or die("Couldn't connect to database");

if ($_POST['login']){
    if ($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password']){
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string(hash("sha512", $_POST['password']));
        $user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Username`='$username'"));
        if ($user == '0'){
            die("That username does not exist. <a href='index.php'>&larr; Back</a>");
            echo "<h1> Test </h1>";
        }
        if ($user['Password'] != $password) {
            die("Incorrect password! <a href='index.php'>&larr; Back</a>");
            echo "<h1> Test </h1>";
        }
        $salt = hash("sha512", rand() . rand() . rand());
        setcookie("c_user", hash("sha512", $username), time() + 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
        setcookie("c_salt", $salt, time() + 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
        $userID = $user['ID'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `Salt`='$salt' WHERE `ID`='$userID'");
        die("You are now logged in as $username");
    }
}

echo "
    <body style='font=family: verdana, sans-serif;'>
        <div>
            <h1>Login to Access Coins</h1>
            <br />
            <form action='' method='post'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b> Username </b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type='text' name='username' style='padding: 6px;' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Password</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='password' name='password' style='padding: 6px;' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type='submit' value='Login' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <br />
            <h6>
                Need an account? <a href='register.php'>Click Here
            </h6>
        </div>
    </body>

";
```

Comment: "post function doesn't appear to be working"  what does that mean?

Comment: I introduce you a new friend, that will help you everytime you get a parameter wrong or missing on form submission : `print_r($_POST);`
You will see whether or not the values are correctly passed to your page.

Comment: @developerwjk : We must say "post method doesn't appear to be working", is it right ?

Comment: @technico Where should I put this?

Comment: @technico I did not see anything in the console when I put that command before the "if post login" statement

Comment: almost anywhere would fit :) The better place would be to cut your big echo statement after the body tag, put the print_r($_POST) there, then echo the last part of your HTML code.
The result will be displayed on the page. If values don't pass, you will see something like `POST => array();`; Else you will see the values.

Comment: @technico It appears to be working. When I tried out something I got this: Array ( [username] => ihhiu [password] => kmkk )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem come from the fact you expect $_POST['login'] to be defined, and rely on it to log the user. As login is not defined, you can simply remove (or comment for further use ) :

```
if ($_POST['login']){
```

and the corresponding

```
}
```

Another way of solving this would be to put :

```
 <input name="login" type ="hidden" value="">
```

inside your form for this value can be passed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to solve this all day! @technico